# Adding new accent colors and brushes (MahApps)

Tags: xaml, mahapps.metro

I'm in the process of converting an application to use the MahApps colour and brush resources, to allow us to programmatically change the application theme/accent.

I need a very pale accented background colour (which will be used in dozens of places, and by different types of control), but the palest MahApps colour ("AccentColor4") isn't light enough. Short of modifying the MahApps library, is there any way to create additional Color and Brush resources in my application that would somehow be able to alter their colour based on the current MahApps accent?

Comment: I answered a similar question [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36147698/how-to-create-a-custom-accent-in-mahapps-metro/36169095#36169095).

Comment: @jstreet so I would have to create new accents by copying the existing MahApps accents then adding my new colour? That's a shame - I just need a lighter version of one particular colour, so was hoping there would be a clever way to somehow inherit or override it, or alter its opacity. I'll have a rethink about my design...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, I think I'd add a new key to my `Accent` (maybe `AccentColor5`?) based on the `AccentColor4` value.

[Here](https://github.com/punker76/code-samples/blob/master/MahAppsMetroThemesSample/MahAppsMetroThemesSample/ThemeManagerHelper.cs) you can find a `ThemeManagerHelper` class made by [punker76](https://github.com/punker76), which might help you calculating `AccentColor5` from `AccentColor4` (see `CreateAppStyleBy` method).

I also made this, which should make your life easier:

```
private void AddKeyForCurrentAccent(object key, object value, bool changeAccentImmediately = false)
{
    Tuple<MahApps.Metro.AppTheme, MahApps.Metro.Accent> currentAppStyle = MahApps.Metro.ThemeManager.DetectAppStyle(Application.Current);

    if(currentAppStyle.Item2.Resources.Contains(key))
    {
        currentAppStyle.Item2.Resources.Remove(key);
    }

    currentAppStyle.Item2.Resources.Add(key, value);

    if(changeAccentImmediately)
    {
        var accentName = string.Format("CustomTheme.xaml");

        CreateAccentFrom(accentName, currentAppStyle.Item2.Resources);

        MahApps.Metro.ThemeManager.ChangeAppStyle(Application.Current, MahApps.Metro.ThemeManager.GetAccent(accentName), currentAppStyle.Item1);
    }
}

private void CreateAccentFrom(string accentName, ResourceDictionary resourceDictionary)
{
    var fileName = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.IO.Path.GetTempPath(), accentName);

    using (var writer = System.Xml.XmlWriter.Create(fileName, new System.Xml.XmlWriterSettings { Indent = true }))
    {
        System.Windows.Markup.XamlWriter.Save(resourceDictionary, writer);
        writer.Close();
    }

    resourceDictionary = new ResourceDictionary() { Source = new Uri(fileName, UriKind.Absolute) };

    var newAccent = new MahApps.Metro.Accent { Name = accentName, Resources = resourceDictionary };

    MahApps.Metro.ThemeManager.AddAccent(accentName, newAccent.Resources.Source);
}
```

`AddKeyForCurrentAccent` will add (or replace - if it already exists) a key in the current `Accent` for the application.

If `changeAccentImmediately` is set to true, it will create a new file and save the new `Accent` (with the inserted/replaced keys) and set it as the `Accent` for the application

**TIP**: You can add/replace all the keys you want and set `changeAccentImmediately` to true only on the last one (this should improve performance).

Use it like this:

```
AddKeyForCurrentAccent("AccentColor5", Brushes.Pink); // Does not replace the accent immediately (so changes are not visible) - works faster

// AND/OR

AddKeyForCurrentAccent("AccentColor5", Brushes.HotPink, true); // Will update the UI
```

**IMPORTANT:** Please note that if you use your custom keys, and you forget to add it to your `Accent`, it'll use the default value for that type.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks you! If you have any trouble please let me know :)