# How to add .xaml to create a custom Theme on MahApps.Metro

Tags: c#, mahapps.metro

I'm new to WPF in general and now I was trying to make a custom theme, specifically a Dark Mode (using others colors, not the default BaseDark), so I was reading the documentation here:

https://mahapps.com/guides/styles.html#custom

But I don't know what to do with it. That code is a .xaml, right? like BaseDark.xaml referenced in App.xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/BaseDark.xaml" />
```

So, how do I implement it into the project? I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36147698/how-to-create-a-custom-accent-in-mahapps-metro) that I had to "create MyCustomAccent.xaml under Styles/Accents folder" but I have no idea how to do that and the post is old

**So that's the question, how do I add my custom .xaml Theme to my project?**

I know that later I have to use the ThemeManager.ChangeAppTheme to switch between BaseLight and my CustomDark, I already made a toggle button that does that between BaseLight and BaseDark

Answer (score -2):

This page has a step by step for you: https://mahapps.com/guides/quick-start.html#styling

The idea is that you add the styles dictionary to the Window like so:

```
<Application x:Class="WpfApplication.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
  <Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
      <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <!-- MahApps.Metro resource dictionaries. Make sure that all file names are Case Sensitive! -->
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Fonts.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Colors.xaml" />
        <!-- Accent and AppTheme setting -->
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/Blue.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/BaseLight.xaml" />
      </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
  </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```